# When I run this code I get the stackOverflow error

Tags: java, image-processing, stack-overflow

I have to get the values and I have to match the pixels values in my image. But When I run this code I get the `StackOverflowError`.

How to increase the stack memory in java to overcome this issue.

```java
public class ImageToText {
    private final int ALPHA = 24;
    private final int RED = 16;
    private final int GREEN = 8;
    private final int BLUE = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\image.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int color21=image.getHeight();
        int color31=image.getWidth();
        getRGBA(image,color31,color21);

        for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++)
            {
                int color = image.getRGB(j, i);
                int color2=image.getHeight();
                int color3=image.getWidth();
                System.out.println(color2);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] getRGBA(BufferedImage img, int x, int y)
    {
        int[] color = new int[4];
        int[] originalPixel =  getRGBA(img,x,y);

        for (int i=0;i<img.getWidth();i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<img.getHeight();j++)
            {
                int[] color1 =  getRGBA(img,i,j);

                if (originalPixel[0] == color1[0] && originalPixel[1] == color1[1] && originalPixel[2] == color1[2] && originalPixel[3] == color1[3])
                {
                    img.setRGB(i, j,Color.red.getRGB());
                }
                else
                {
                    img.setRGB(i, j,Color.yellow.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

How to overcome this Error?

Comment: show error stack trace pls

Comment: `public static int[] getRGBA(BufferedImage img, int x, int y)
{
int[] color = new int[4];
int[] originalPixel =  getRGBA(img,x,y);` This will loop forever. You have to find another way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: I want to overcome this error and how to overcome this problem. I have to match the pixels and if the pixel values match I will change the pixel value.

Comment: @Sheela Kannan: This is pretty basic stuff. The VM is even telling you where the problem is. It might be helpful if you let everyone know what your programming experience is. Do you understand what it means when these people say "infinite recursion", or "calls itself indefinitely"?

Comment: I know the infinite recursion. But the problem is this code can be simplified in anyway?

Comment: It is not really about simplification. It is about writing a correct recursion, you need a base case.

Comment: what's the code *supposed to do*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getRGBA calls itself infinitely:

```
public static int[] getRGBA(BufferedImage img, int x, int y)

  {

int[] color = new int[4];


 int[] originalPixel =  getRGBA(img,x,y);
```

This sort of thing causes a StackOverflowError.

**Consider adding the base case of recursion**, so that your code doesn't always call itself and has a "way out".

Comment: so tell me to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

This line in function getRGBA :

```
int[] originalPixel =  getRGBA(img,x,y);
```

This should cause infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

From the `main` method you are calling the below `getRGBA` method. Inside the `getRGBA` method you are calling the method again. This makes a cyclic/recursive execution with no exit criteria.

```
public static int[] getRGBA(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
    int[] color = new int[4];
    int[] originalPixel =  getRGBA(img,x,y);
}
```

You must add some condition around the method call so that the recursive execution stops. Your feature is not clear enough to suggest what condition you can put.

```
public static int[] getRGBA(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
    int[] color = new int[4];
    if (some condition which becomes true) {
        int[] originalPixel =  getRGBA(img,x,y);
    }
}
```